# How to add JUCE to Android app without GUI/Projuce?

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, juce

I have an already working audio app for Android that uses [Oboe](https://github.com/google/oboe). I found some nice plugins https://github.com/juandagilc/Audio-Effects that I'd like to add to my project.

I made JUCE compile successfully on my Android Studio project, but now I'm wondering what I should do next. The [mobile tutorial](https://docs.juce.com/master/tutorial_android_studio.html)  only talks about Projuce, bit what if I want to just produce music, without any of the things from Projuce? I just want to use JUCE as an audio processing library.

All the JUCE tutorials are more linked to using the GUI provided by Juce, but how can I use it for just audio processing, that is, as a true library?

Comment: I think https://forum.juce.com/ is the best platform for this question.

Comment: I'm having the same question :)

Comment: Did you manage to use it in the end? I have a similar situation.

Comment: @Rene yes you can just create an android example and strip some things out. It's not hard, you just have to understand how it builds and links and etc